# How can I pass two possible type to T in C# generic class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository-pattern, generic-programming

I have implemented `Repository Pattern` in `Asp.Net Core` application. I'm using generic class for base repository:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IDisposable, IGenericRepository<T>, IGenericRepositoryAsync<T>
    where T : BaseEntity, new()
{
    // Standard methods like: GetById, Update, Delete etc.
}
```

I have Specific repositories following my `Domain`: `FeedRepository`, `UserRepository`. And `Entities`: `Post`, `ApplicationUser`.

My `FeedRepository` looks like this:

```
public class FeedRepository : GenericRepository<Post>, IFeedRepository
{
    // Specific methods for Feed
}
```

The problem is that I need to use `GenericRepository` for all my other repositories, but my `ApplicationUser` entity extends `IdentityUser` not `BaseEntity`.

Is there any way to have 2 possible types for GenericRepository? Can `T` be sometimes `BaseEntity` and sometimes `IdentityUser`?

Comment: That's an *anti*pattern when used on top of ORMs like NHibernate or EntityFramework.  ORMs are higher-level abstractions. Using a `BaseEntity` is another problem. ORMs allow you to use any class while adding that type does the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in theory, you could do this:

```
public class GenericRepository<T, TBase> : IDisposable, IGenericRepository<T>, IGenericRepositoryAsync<T>
    where T : TBase, new()
{
    // Standard methods like: GetById, Update, Delete etc.
}
```

But it's unclear to me what that would accomplish. Usually when you use generic criteria it's because something in your class knows how to interact with the type in the criteria (`BaseEntity`) in some special way.

If that's not the case, then there's no real purpose for that criteria in the first place, and you should just remove it.

If that *is* the case, you should probably create a separate repository type. For example, you can have a `GenericEntityRepository` and then a separate `IdentityUserRepository` or something like that.